# Mocking HttpClient for component testing an aurelia class

Tags: testing, integration-testing, aurelia

I have an aurelia class which looks like this:

```
import {HttpClient} from 'aurelia-fetch-client'

export class Lobby {
  constructor() {
    this.propertyName = 'description'
  }

  fetch() {
    new HttpClient().fetch('/api/package.json')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.response = data[this.propertyName] || Object.keys(data)
      })
  }
}
```

I want add a component test for this class where I trigger `#fetch()` and control the server response in my test, essentially mock the http backend. My tests looks like this:

```
describe('the lobby', () => {
  let component
  beforeEach(done => {
    component = StageComponent.withResources('lobby')
      .inView('<lobby></lobby>')
      .boundTo({})

    component.bootstrap(aurelia => {
      aurelia.use.standardConfiguration()
    })

    component.create(bootstrap).then(() => {
      window.Promise = Promise
      done()
    })
  })

  it('should fetch a result via HttpClient', (done) => {
    const inputElement = document.querySelector('input');
    const button = document.querySelector('button')
    const output = () => document.querySelector('pre')
    expect(inputElement.value).toBe('description')
    button.click()

    waitFor(() => output().innerText !== '').then(() => {
      expect(output().innerText).toBe('foo');
      done()
    })
  })
})
```

This does not work because aurelia-fetch-client performs an actual HTTP request and there is no backend running. How do I mock the HttpClient in a way that I have control over the response?

Note: `#waitFor()` is a function that I derived from [here](https://github.com/aurelia/testing/blob/master/src/wait.js), I created a gist with it [here](https://gist.github.com/konqi/afbe8f956c3012eca57b9e9888590aa5). I have created a [pull request](https://github.com/aurelia/testing/pull/62) for my version of the `#waitFor()`. When it gets accepted the gist becomes irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch to using injected services. Your aurelia class would look like this:

```
import {HttpClient} from 'aurelia-fetch-client'
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework'

@inject(HttpClient)
export class Lobby {
  constructor(httpClient) {
    this.HttpClient = httpClient
    this.propertyName = 'description'
  }

  fetch() {
    this.HttpClient.fetch('/api/package.json')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.response = data[this.propertyName] || Object.keys(data)
      })
  }
}
```

Notice the `@inject(HttpClient)` instead of simply using the imported HttpClient. This way you can inject a mock for the HttpClient from within your tests like this:

```
import { StageComponent } from 'aurelia-testing'
import { bootstrap } from 'aurelia-bootstrapper'
import { HttpClient } from 'aurelia-fetch-client'

describe('the lobby', () => {
  let component
  beforeEach(done => {
    component = StageComponent.withResources('lobby')
      .inView('<lobby></lobby>')
      .boundTo({})

    component.bootstrap(aurelia => {
      aurelia.use.standardConfiguration()
      aurelia.container.autoRegister(HttpClient, class {
        fetch(url) {
          return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve({
              json: () => { return { "description": "foo" } }
            })
          })
        }
      })
    })

    component.create(bootstrap).then(() => {
      window.Promise = Promise
      done()
    })
  })
})
```